# How can I let me website and UWP JavaScript app access the same database?

Tags: javascript, html, uwp

I am running a Flask based website that uses a MySQL database, but I am making a UWP JavaScript app for the windows store and I need to be able to access the same database. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The better way is that you could create WebApi to access `database` in the web service and then exposed restful api for your uwp app. In uwp client app sent get or post request to get the data.